# Radial Solution To The Heat Equation $u_t=u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

1. Find a function $G(t,r,s)$ such that $u(t,x,y,z)=\int_0^\infty G(t,\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},s)f(s)\, ds$
   is a solution for the problem $u_t=u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}$ such that $u(0,x,y,z)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})$.

2.$u(t,x,y,z)$ is solution for $u_t=u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}$ such that $u(0,x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $|u(t,x,y,z)|\le c(t)e^\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
calculate $u(t,0,0,0)$.

Attempted solution: lets find a radial solution
$u_t=u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r} u_r$
let $v=ru$ so we get $v_t=v_{rr}$
and $v(0,r)=rf(r)$ lets note that $0\lt r$
so we do a even extension and then we get
$v(t,r)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{(r-s)^2}{4t}}sf(s)\, ds +\frac{1} {\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{(r+s)^2}{4t}}sf(s)\, ds $
after simplifactions we get
$v(t,r)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{\pi t}} \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2+s^2}{4t}}sinh(\frac{rs}{2t})sf(s)\, ds$

so $G(t,r,s)= \frac{e^{-\frac{r^2+s^2}{4t}}sinh(\frac{rs}{2t})}{r\sqrt{\pi t}}$

And when i tried to use this in order to solve B.

I got a that $u(t,0,0,0)=-\infty$
which is obviously wrong.

(why do we need the condition $|u(t,x,y,z)|\le c(t)e^\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ ?)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of part 1 has a few typos:

- You should do an odd, instead of even, extension for $v(t,r)$, since $v$ must vanish at the origin:
  $$
  v(t,r)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{(r-s)^2}{4t}}sf(s)\, ds \color\red{-}\frac{1} {\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{(r+s)^2}{4t}}sf(s)\, ds. \tag{1}
  $$
- Despite that, you obtained the correct expression for $v(t,r)$, but missed a factor of $s$ when writing $G(t,r,s)$:
  $$
  G(t,r,s)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{\pi t}} e^{-\frac{r^2+s^2}{4t}}\sinh\left(\frac{rs}{2t}\right)\frac{\color\red{s}}{r}. \tag{2}
  $$

To calculate $u(t,0)$, we first notice that
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}G(t,r,s)=\frac{1} {\sqrt{\pi t}} e^{-\frac{s^2}{4t}}\left(\frac{s^2}{2t}\right). \tag{3}
$$
Then, with $f(s)=s$, we obtain
\begin{align}
u(t,0)&=\lim_{r\to 0}\int_0^{\infty}G(t,r,s)s\,ds \\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{s^2}{4t}}s^3\,ds \\
&=\frac{8t^2}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}}=4\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}. \tag{4}
\end{align}